# SQL Query : Fetch Entire Row with Minimum value in the table

Tags: sql, t-sql

What will be the optimized query for pulling out various columns of a row which HOLDS a minimum value for a particular column.

For e.g Displaying Name and the salary of all the persons which holds the minimum salary in the category of Permanent Employees from the below table which has just three columns in it

> Employee (Name, EmployeeType, Salary)

EmployeeType Can be Permanent or Temporary
I already know a solution but I think there might be a better way.
My solution is :

```
Select E.*  from Employee Where 
Salary = (Select Min(Salary) From Employee Where EmployeeType='P') 
and EmployeeType='P'
```

Comment: I think your query is OK! (except for the syntax error: change `E.*` to just `*`)

Comment: @Bohemian: Thanks for editing, E.* was just a way to say that I will pull all the columns by explicitly mentioning names

Comment: I thought of avoiding EmployeeType Condition again but cant find a better solution than this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the minimum salary is shared by more than one employee, you can retrieve all of them using the `TOP (1) WITH TIES` construct:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES *
FROM Employee
WHERE EmployeeType = 'P'
ORDER BY Salary
```

Reference:

- [TOP (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM Employee
WHERE EmployeeType = 'P'
ORDER BY Salary ASC
```

In MySQL, you could use `LIMIT 1`. In Oracle you could use an inner query combined with `WITH rownum = 1`.

This will always return one row, even if there are several employees sharing a minimum salary. You could add additional ordering columns if you want to specify which of those rows to return.

If you instead want to return all such rows, the OP's query would be the most optimal:

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee
WHERE Salary = (
    SELECT MIN(Salary)
    FROM Empoyee
    WHERE EmployeeType = 'P'
)
AND EmployeeType = 'P'
```

Comment: What if two employees have minimum salary, Top 1 will always return one row

Comment: No Offense but I am little surprised 4 people voting this up, nobody thought of top n issues with equal values

Comment: Yes! I should have been more precise with the english. I can still edit it. Thanks for that.